# I would like to generate a array like this [ 1, 2, ..., 9, 10 ] in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

if *count* is 4, *arr* will be [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]

if *count* is greater than 4, *arr* will be like [ 1, 2, "...", 9, 10 ]

I tried this way, but output is [ 1, 2, "..." ]

```
const arr = [];

const count = 10;

for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    if (i >= 8) {
        arr.push(i + 1);
        continue;
    }
    if (i >= 2) {
        arr.push("...");
        break;
    }

    arr.push(i + 1);
}
```

Comment: Because `break` stops the loop.

Comment: There's no path that would produce the expected output for `count === 4` (`i === 3`). If you find a way to fix that `break`, you're missing a step to actually skip the elements that are then represented by the `...` in the array.

Comment: Is the limit of how many items there can be in the array always going to be 4, or can it change in the future?

Comment: Another take, cause i found it funny: `const assert = (test, msg) => { if (!test) throw new Error(msg); }; function* range(start, end) { for (let i = start; i <= end; i++) yield i; } function* abb(start, end, displayCount) { assert(Number.isInteger(start) && Number.isInteger(end) && Number.isInteger(displayCount) && displayCount > 0 && end - start >= 0, 'Input should be valid.'); if (end - start + 1 > 2 * displayCount) { yield* range(start, start + displayCount - 1); yield '...'; yield* range(end - displayCount + 1, end); } else yield* range(start, end); } console.log([...abb(7, 16, 3)]);`

Answer (score 3):

From what I see from the OP's expected outputs/results it looks like the problem was more about creating kind of a sequence with ellipsis. In this case one could choose a much simpler approach.

Any sequence with a `count` lower than and equal to `4` will be created via [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and its optional [`mapFn`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#using_arrow_functions_and_array.from) parameter. For any `count` value which exceeds `4` there is no necessity of using any kind of loop; just create an array with the first two items which are always `1` and `2`, followed by the ellipsis placeholder of `'...'`, followed by the last two items which always have the values of `count - 1` respectively `count`.

```js
function createEllipsisSequence(count) {
  let list;
  if (count <= 4) {

    list = Array
      .from({ length: count }, (_, idx) => idx + 1);
      
  } else {
    list = [1, 2, '...', count - 1, count];
  }
  return list;
}

console.log('count: 3 ...',
  createEllipsisSequence(3)
);
console.log('count: 4 ...',
  createEllipsisSequence(4)
);

console.log('count: 5 ...',
  createEllipsisSequence(5)
);
console.log('count: 6 ...',
  createEllipsisSequence(6)
);

console.log('count: 10 ...',
  createEllipsisSequence(10)
);
console.log('count: 11 ...',
  createEllipsisSequence(11)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd write this as

```
let i=0;
for (; i < count && i < 2; i++) {
    arr.push(i + 1);
}
if (count > 4) {
    arr.push("…");
    i = count - 2;
}
for (; i < count; i++) {
    arr.push(i + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can predefine it in the if as well and then use the loop.

```js
let arr =

 [];
const count = 10;

if (count <= 4) {
  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    arr.push(i);
  }
} else {
  arr = [1, 2, '...', count - 1, count];
}
console.log(arr);
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/trishantpahwa/5pcyrbLd/4/)

Answer (score 0):

You could handle the edges in one `if` and another case for the `...`

```js
let arr = [];

const count = 10;

for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  
  if (i < 2 || i >= count - 2) {
    arr.push(i + 1)
  } else if (i === 2) {
    arr.push('...');
  }
}

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: appreciate for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a function to which you send `count` and you would receive back the desired array. The function will return `[]` if `count` is less than 4. **To return `[1], [1,2], [1,2,3]` for counts `1, 2, 3` change `0` in `Array(......0)` to `count`.**

```js
const fun = count => Array(count === 4 ? 4 : count > 4 ? 5 : 0).fill('')
                     .map((e, i, a) => 
                         a.length === 4 || i < 2 ? i + 1 : i === 2 ? "..." : i + 6
                     );
                     
console.log( fun(0) );

console.log( fun(4) );

console.log( fun(6) );
```

Your code needs a few corrections. You can employ a loop as follows:

```js
const arr = [];

const count = 10;

for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    if (i >= 8) {
        arr.push(i + 1);
        continue;
    }
    if (count > 4) {
        if( i === 2 ) {
            arr.push("...");
        } else if( i < 2 ) {
            arr.push(i + 1);
        }
        continue;
    }

    arr.push(i + 1);
}

console.log( arr );
```

Comment: "*The function will return `[]` if count is less than 4.*" - that's not what the OP wants

Comment: @Bergi, you don't know for sure that that is not what he wants. If you do, what is it?

Comment: I can't be 100% certain, since it's not stated explicitly in the question, but both the OP's original code as well as every other answer generates the sequence [1..count] for counts <=4. It seems to be the reasonable thing to not introduce yet another special case.

Answer (score -1):

Two simle functions

1. make an array from 1 to N
2. ellipsis an array

```js
const makeList = (size) => [...Array(size + 1).keys()].slice(1);
const ellipsisList = (list) => (list.length <= 4) 
   ? list
   : [list.at(0), list.at(1), '...', list.at(-2), list.at(-1)];
   

console.log(ellipsisList(makeList(4)));
console.log(ellipsisList(makeList(6)));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```